# Set ssl only on one page on apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https

I am having Spring application and I like to set only one page from my application to run on https , all the other pages to run on http.

I have this configuration in my web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>SSL Pages</web-resource-name>        
    <url-pattern>/external/success</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>    
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I have this configuration in server.xml file:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="/opt/apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.55-test/conf/test.jks"  keystorePass="changeit" keyAlias="test" />
```

My application is still running on both http and https and the desired page is open only on https. How can I make restrictions to my application.

Comment: Why do you care if the other pages are served without SSL?

Comment: I have that requirement. Other pages are served with and without SSL, I like to be served without SSL. Only one page to be served with SSL

Comment: @vikifor, could you set two Host with two separate deployment directories?